# Get array textfield and calculate javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

forexample, i have this code (results from a php script loop):

`<input type="text" name="qtty[]" id="qtty[]" onFocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();">
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price[]">
<input type="text" name="totalprice[]" id="totalprice[]">`

And this for javascript:

```
function startCalc(){
    interval = setInterval("calc()",500);
}

function calc(){
$('input[name="qtty[]"]').each(function(){
    qtty    = $(this).val();
});
$('input[name="price[]"]').each(function(){
    price   = $(this).val();
});
total   = (qtty * 1) * (price * 1);
$('input[name="totalprice[]"]').val(total);

}


function stopCalc(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

The moment I enter the first input to the array, the program does not show anything. but at the time of the second array of data fed, TotalPrice will change both

Here, Example pict:

1. http://s7.postimg.org/memsupuh7/Capture1.png
2. http://s23.postimg.org/6rdfk2rzf/Capture.png

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Comment: What is the need of .each( in your code? You are not adding those values anymore..

Comment: So what id should be unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in the wrong way. This is more preferred variant:

```
<input type="text" name="qtty">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="2">
<input type="text" name="totalprice">
<br>
<input type="text" name="qtty">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="3">
<input type="text" name="totalprice">
```

and

```
$('input[name="qtty"]').keyup(function() {
  var qtty = $(this).val();
  var price = $(this).next().val(); 
  var total = (qtty * 1) * (price * 1);
  $(this).nextAll().eq(1).val(total); 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq2Cu/2/)

Comment: But why if i use table for place that textfield it didn't work ?
http://jsfiddle.net/andy_yatma_s/xq2Cu/6/

Comment: this is because of this expression : `$(this).nextAll().eq(1).val(total);`
it is mean: second element after this or simply totalprise input, but you put it in other `<td/>` so it is not works.

Comment: use for example this  `$(this).parent().next().children().val(total);`
http://jsfiddle.net/xq2Cu/7/

Comment: but if you change structure of table - you must rewrite this rule

Comment: Wow... it works.
Thanks dude, you just save my life :D

Comment: You are welcome, but don't forget to edit nesting if you will rebuild the table or just add another element

Answer (score 0):

try this

Assign the default value initially

```
    var qtty=0;
    var price =0;
    var interval ;
        function startCalc(){
            interval = setInterval(calc,500);
        }

        function calc(){
        $('input[name="qtty[]"]').each(function(){
            qtty    = $(this).val();
        });
        $('input[name="price[]"]').each(function(){
            price   = $(this).val();
        });
        total   = (qtty * 1) * (price * 1);
        $('input[name="totalprice[]"]').val(total);

        }


        function stopCalc(){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
```